# Using QGIS expressions to edit columns automatically according to a repeating pattern, similar to Excel dropdown/autofill

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, excel

I have a geoJSON file with 4,500 rows. I need to edit this file as follow:

- if **plot_num** starts with 2 -> **rep** = 2
- first 11 rows of **line** = 1
- second 11 rows of **line** = 2

I have been updating the fields manually, but it is taking me for ever and I have 8 files that need the same. How can I use the Expression Dialog tool in QGIS to do so? I wish it was like Excel where I can just copy and paste or use the corner dropdown tool. Can you write a QGIS expression or a Python function to be used in QGIS?

Example (24 rows/4,500 rows):

```
line    rep     plot_num
1       2       256
1       2       256
1       2       256
1       2       256
1       2       256
1       2       256
1       2       256
1       2       256
1       2       256
1       2       256
1       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
2       2       256
1       3       356
1       3       356
```

Comment: Yes, I am. I added new fields (line and rep) to the file and now adding the numbers manually.

Comment: @BERA have an answer? You can post it and explain it.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html?highlight=expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one single expression to create each of the fields at once:

1. To create the value of field `rep` as the first character of field `plot_num`, use this expression:

   `left (plot_num , 1)`
2. To create the field `line` like: the first 11 features of each `plot_num` with value 1, the rest with value 2, use this expression:

   ```
    with_variable (
        'plot',
        plot_num,
        if (
            array_min (array_agg( $id, filter:=plot_num=@plot)) + 11 <= $id,
            2,1
        )
    )
   ```

[image]

Comment: Would you please review your code? It runned for about 10 mins on my MacBook Pro (32GB RAM) for about 10 mins and I couldn't get QGIS to respond. Should I keep waiting or try a PC with more RAM?

Comment: How many features do you have? How large is your data set? I think that is the problem.

Comment: I have about 20 features (columns) x 4500 rows.

Comment: Columns are called `fields`, rows are `features`. In my screenshot, I have 4 fields (attributes) and over 33 features. So maybe 4500 feautures is just too much? So the problem is with the second expression only, right? The first one was OK?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Problem was only with second expression.

Comment: I used a PC with more memory and it worked as expected. Great answer BTW!

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out that you can use the tool "Select features using an expression" and then update the fields using "Open field calculator".
On the "Select features using an expression" I used the following to find the empty "rep" fields where "plot_num" was 1.

```
CASE
WHEN left("plot_num",1) IS 1 THEN "rep" is NULL
END
```

Once those where selected, I updated their values using "Open field calculator" by selecting the field that needed to be updated and setting the desired value.